# Which materials dumped into landfills are the largest sources of methane?

Tags: waste, greenhouse-gas-emissions, biodegradable-waste

Recent [research](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/s41586-019-1720-3) has shown that landfills (garbage dumps) can be major emitters of methane.

> The largest methane emitters in California are a subset of landfills, which exhibit persistent anomalous activity. Methane point-source emissions in California are dominated by landfills (41 per cent), followed by dairies (26 per cent) and the oil and gas sector (26 per cent).

Which materials being placed into landfills are likely to be the source of all this methane? I am particularly curious about whether plastic plays much of a role here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The source of methane -- degradable organic carbon

A 2006 report by the IPCC, [Guidelines for National Greenhouse Gas Inventories, Volume 5 -- Waste](https://www.ipcc-nggip.iges.or.jp/public/2006gl/vol5.html), includes six different categories of landfilled waste which contain **degradable organic carbon (DOC)**. Under anaerobic conditions, the DOC in these materials ultimately decomposes into carbon dioxide (CO<sub>2</sub>) and methane (CH<sub>4</sub>). The eight categories are listed below, with the fraction (by weight) of DOC generally in each. Finally, I included the percent of landfill material that each category constitutes in North America (chosen since you reference California in the question -- data for other regions is available [in the spreadsheet tool](https://www.ipcc-nggip.iges.or.jp/public/2006gl/pdf/5_Volume5/IPCC_Waste_Model.xls)).

```
CATEGORY             % DOC    % LANDFILL COMPOSITION
-----------         ------    ----------------------
Food waste            15               34
Garden                20                0
Paper                 40               23
Wood and straw        43                6
Natural textiles      24                4
Disposable nappies    24                0
```

(Some garden waste is included with food waste. Nappies (diapers) have a value of 0 for all regions -- I'm not really sure why they aren't included, or what assumptions are made that allow them to be excluded here.)

Based on these assumptions, **food waste and paper/cardboard are the largest sources of degradable organic carbon in landfills**.

### How much of it becomes methane?

The amount of emissions from the decomposition that becomes methane depends on the type of landfill and how it is managed:

> Waste disposal practices vary in the control, placement of waste and management of the site. The CH<sub>4</sub> correction factor (MCF) accounts for the fact that unmanaged SWDS [solid waste disposal sites] produce less CH<sub>4</sub> from a given amount of waste than anaerobic managed SWDS.

The MCF by SWDS types are:

> [image: MCF by SWDS assumptions]

In a managed, anaerobic landfill, all of the DOC decomposes into methane. This is the "gold standard" in landfills, and in the U.S., the EPA [requires most large landfills to collect this methane](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=9dd547da709a41416ae82bf206af61c9&mc=true&r=SECTION&n=se40.27.258_123), where it is typically burned to produce electricity.

#### How much of the methane is released to the atmosphere?

The amount of methane captured at landfills varies widely, but in practice rates of up to 90% are feasible:

> There  have  been  some  measurements  of  efficiencies  at  gas  recovery  projects,  and  reported  efficiencies  have  been  between  10  and  85  percent.  Oonk  and  Boom  (1995)  measured  efficiencies  at  closed,  unlined SWDS to be in between 10 and 80 percent, the average over 11 SWDS being 37 percent. More recently Scharff et al. (2003) measured efficiencies at four SWDS to be 9 percent, 50 percent, 55 percent and 33 percent. Spokas et  al.  (2006)  and  Diot  et  al.  (2001)  recently  measured  efficiencies  above  90  percent.

---

#### Bonus Q: How much food is wasted?

The assumption is that 34% of what is sent to landfills is food waste. How does this compare to the amount of food produced?

From [a 2010 article in Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/earth-talk-waste-land/):

> According to the U.S. Department of Agriculture’s Food Loss Project, we throw away more than 25 percent—some 25.9 million tons—of all the food we produce for domestic sale and consumption. A 2004 University of Arizona study pegs the figure at closer to 50 percent [...]

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder what the leakage rate is like in practice at those managed anaerobic sites. It won't be zero, not from a big messy gas system

Comment: @ChrisH good question, and as I suspected, the IPCC also addressed this -- I edited the answer to include their findings.

Comment: It seems like a good idea to burn this methane by having plastic pipe in the landfill to  collect gases. This was done in IL but the EPA made then extinguish the fires and just vent the gas.

Comment: Looks like the [2019 update to this report](https://www.ipcc-nggip.iges.or.jp/public/2019rf/vol5.html) was published days after I wrote this answer.