# Is litter better than an unmanaged landfill?

Tags: waste

In landfill conditions, it takes everything forever to decompose, especially plastics. Proper lining, methane capture, it's what developed countries have, and most countries are not developed. So could litter be better than an unmanaged landfill?

Landfilling doesn't deal with, only masks the problem of waste, including plastic waste. Maybe it's a radical idea, but is litter actually a good thing? With oxygen and sunlight available, it will decompose faster, and that way it kinda says, "Hey, look at me, pay attention to me, I exist", so maybe it's more likely to be actually handled (recycled, composted, most importantly prevented). If it's something dangerous, you incinerate it. I can't think of anything for which an unmanaged landfill is the best option.

Comment: If you think waste might belong somewhere other than a landfill, could you update your post to be more specific about where litter should be? Left in the streets, perhaps?

Comment: Related: [Which materials dumped into landfills are the largest sources of methane?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/9689/3379).

Comment: Plastic litter is bad. It slowly degrades into tiny pieces of micro-plastics that is very hard to clean-up and may end up in groundwater. Also animals may eat plastics or get entangled in them and eventually die. I strongly doubt that leaving it as a signal "that it needs to be handled differently" will work. Look for example at cigarette butts. They are mostly made of plastic and are the most commonly found type of litter. Hardly anything is done to change this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answer was written before the question was changed to specifically ask about landfills in developing countries.*

---

**tl;dr: No, because landfills are the best place to capture carbon escaping from degradable materials, prevent toxic chemicals from entering the groundwater, and to store non-degradable materials.**

### Capturing landfill gas

[According to the U.S. Environmental Protection Agency](https://www.epa.gov/facts-and-figures-about-materials-waste-and-recycling/national-overview-facts-and-figures-materials), nearly 60% of the municipal solid waste (MSW) that is landfilled in the U.S. consists of degradable materials such as paper, food, wood, and yard waste:

[image: Total municipal solid waste landfill by material, 2018]

All of these materials will eventually biodegrade into methane and carbon dioxide. In a managed, anaerobic landfill with methane capture, nearly all of the methane can be captured and used to generate electricity. If such waste were left as litter, these gases would escape directly to the atmosphere, contributing to the greenhouse effect without doing any useful work along the way.

In the U.S., methane capture is [required](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-40/chapter-I/subchapter-I/part-258/subpart-C/section-258.23) at most landfills, and the EPA has an [active program](https://www.epa.gov/lmop/about-landfill-methane-outreach-program) to institute methane capture at eligible landfills. [Per the EIA](https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/biomass/landfill-gas-and-biogas.php), landfill gas (LFG) projects in the U.S. in 2020 captured a quantity of methane that, if released to the atmosphere, would represent 100.4 million metric tons of CO<sub>2</sub> equivalent (MMTCO<sub>2</sub>e). This is slightly more than than the 99.4 MMTCO<sub>2</sub>e released from landfills without LFG capture, [according the the EPA](https://www.epa.gov/lmop/frequent-questions-about-landfill-gas#howmuchmethane).

### Treating leachate

Most LFG collection systems have the benefit of combing with a leachate collection system (image from [EIA](https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/biomass/landfill-gas-and-biogas.php)):

[image: Leachate collection system]

[Leachate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leachate#Composition_of_landfill_leachate) is the nasty mix of liquids and chemicals that ooze out of garbage. It oozes out of all garbage wherever it is, so better to collect it in a landfill where it can be treated, which is typically done in large tanks with the same kind of enzymes and neutralizing chemicals that are used to treat sewage.

The leachate itself is actually a very corrosive substance, which means that it helps break down the stuff in the landfill, increasing methane production and reducing the time it takes for things to break down.

### All the other stuff

As for everything else (mostly metal, glass, and plastic) it originally came from a hole in the ground, so putting back in one seems appropriate.

Comment: You lose digestate, which could be used as a fertilizer, if you don't sort out organic waste and instead send it to landfills. So it's not the perfect option. Besides, it takes decades for organic waste to decompose in landfills' anaerobic conditions. Toxic substances can leach out if lining isn't flawless (and it isn't in many places, if present at all). There's no plastic underground

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev still far better than litter on the ground though, right? You'd be capturing no digestate, and all the toxic substances would leak out. Regarding plastic, it's made from oil, which did come from a hole in the ground.

Comment: The portion of organic litter that is resting on soils will give it its nutrients (N) as it decomposes. In landfills that portion is zero per cent. Landfills are not "holes in the ground" in the fossil fuel sense since they are above groundwater (microplastic). Petroleum and gas are pumped from much greater depths. Proper lining, methane capture, it's what developed countries have, and most countries are not developed

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev then it sounds like your question is whether litter on the ground is better than litter in an unlined, unmanaged landfill? That is unclear in the question.

Comment: Now it is. 4 more to go...

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev 4 more to go? I don't understand.

Comment: Ignore it. 4 more to go...